# Using async/await recursively with node request package

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, recursion, async-await, node-request

I'm making an http request using the `response` node library and I am trying to call it recursively (If the user made a commit on one day, check the previous day. If not, count up all the days to get the streak).

The problem is that the line

```
const githubResponse = await request(options);
```

Spits out the error

```
Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
```

`await request(options)` doesn't seem to return the JSON GitHub API response I am expecting, but instead `githubResponse` seems to be an object that I can't use. I'm guessing I'm using `async/await` improperly, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

```
async function checkUserCommitForDate(user, date) {
    const options = {
        url: `https://api.github.com/search/commits?q=author:${user}+author-date:${date}`,
        headers: {
            'User-Agent': 'request',
            'Accept': 'application/vnd.github.cloak-preview'
        }
    };
    const githubResponse = await request(options)

    // I get an error on the next line

    if (JSON.parse(githubResponse).total_count > 0) {
        const previousDaysDate = moment(date).subtract(1, 'day').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
        let streakCounter = await checkUserCommitForDate(user, previousDaysDate);
        streakCounter++;
        console.log('streakCounter', streakCounter);
        return streakCounter;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

UPDATE: It seems like this is not a promise, so I need to format this differently (as a callback). When I try this:

```
async function checkUserCommitForDate(user, date) {
    const options = {
        url: `https://api.github.com/search/commits?q=author:${user}+author-date:${date}`,
        headers: {
            'User-Agent': 'request',
            'Accept': 'application/vnd.github.cloak-preview'
        }
    };
    request(options, async function (error, response, body) {
        console.log('error:', error); // Print the error if one occurred
        if (JSON.parse(body).total_count > 0) {
            const previousDaysDate = moment(date).subtract(1, 'day').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
            let streakCounter = await checkUserCommitForDate(user, previousDaysDate);
            streakCounter++;
            console.log('streakCounter', streakCounter);
            return streakCounter;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    });
}
```

The line

```
let streakCounter = await checkUserCommitForDate(user, previousDaysDate);
```

becomes the problem as `streakCounter` is undefined, making the log `NaN`.

Comment: Do you use `request` module maybe, not `response`? If so, it doesn't return a promise, but uses callback.

Comment: what is gitubResponse? have you ever console.log it before trying to parse?

Comment: In the update, when I log body, I get JSON and when I parse it I get an object, I'm just still not returning the number, because there is a new problem.

Comment: I don't think you can use await/async with callbacks, they work with Promises. The request package uses callbacks which makes async/await unavailable for use as you can't really return anything from a callback.

Comment: "*so I need to format this differently (as a callback).*" - No. So you need to make a promise for it. Or just use the `request-promise` package instead of `request`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said in the comments [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) uses callbacks instead of returning a promise and you dont really need to promisify it by yourself since there's already a pacakge for that called [request-promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise).

Using it in your code should directly work out of the box with `async/await`

Answer (score 2):

I used [promisify example](https://gist.github.com/TheDeveloper/1312220bfbd27b742628) from here to convert it to this and it worked!

```
async function checkUserCommitForDate(user, date) {
    const options = {
        url: `https://api.github.com/search/commits?q=author:${user}+author-date:${date}`,
        headers: {
            'User-Agent': 'request',
            'Accept': 'application/vnd.github.cloak-preview'
        }
    };

    const githubResponse = await promisify(request)(options);

    if (JSON.parse(githubResponse.body).total_count > 0) {
        const previousDaysDate = moment(date).subtract(1, 'day').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
        let streakCounter = await checkUserCommitForDate(user, previousDaysDate);
        streakCounter++;
        console.log('streakCounter', streakCounter);
        return streakCounter;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

function promisify(fn) {
    return function (...args) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            fn(...args, (err, result) => {
                if (err) return reject(err);
                resolve(result);
            });
        });
    };
};
```

Comment: there's already a request-promise (https://github.com/request/request-promise) module that handles your request promisification

Comment: Thanks Enrique! If you want to create an answer with that in it, I'll mark it as the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

If you are upgraded to Node 8 LTS, then native **util.promisfy** can be used as below:

```
const { promisify } = require('util')
const request = promisify(require('request'))

async function checkUserCommitForDate(user, date) {
  const options = {
    url: `https://api.github.com/search/commits?q=author:${user}+author-date:${date}`,
    headers: {
      'User-Agent': 'request',
      'Accept': 'application/vnd.github.cloak-preview',
      'json':true
    }
  };

  try{
    const githubResponse = await request(options);
    if (githubResponse.body.total_count > 0) {
      const previousDaysDate = moment(date).subtract(1, 'day').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
      let streakCounter = await checkUserCommitForDate(user, previousDaysDate);
      streakCounter++;
      console.log('streakCounter', streakCounter);
      return streakCounter;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
  }
  catch(err){
    console.error(err)
    return 0;
  }
}
```

Using **json:true** in the **options**, will reduce another step to parse as the response will be in *JSON* format.